# XSL : Loop through a node having multiple nodes and find the attributes having same value and merge them in to one cell

Tags: xslt-1.0

Hi I have below sample xml

```
<root>
<test>
     <tester    name="sai"    text="test passed">
     <tester    name="rahul"    text="test failed">
     <tester    name="sai"    text="inprogress">
     <tester    name="rahul"    text="not attended">
     <tester    name="sai"    text="test failed">
</test>
</root>
```

From the above xml I wanted to find the attributes having same names and out put to html by merging in to one cell with the corresponding text attribute values.

Table should have

Sai with rowspan *(auto calculate)* and corresponding text attribute values in 2nd column

Can any one help with xsl code please

Comment: This is a grouping question. Read this and come back if you have a specific question: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: I was looking for grouping around attribute values

Comment: Sorry i am new to XSL .Could you please help with working xsl where i can group using attributes which has same values ?

Comment: There are many examples you can find here if you search for XSLT 1.0 grouping.